# Trying to have 2 list iterators in a for loop

Tags: c++, list, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate through 2 linked lists with this for loop:

```
    for (ListNode* thisCurrent = head, ListNode* current = s.head; thisCurrent != NULL,   
        current != NULL; thisCurrent = thisCurrent->next) {
            //do something
    }
```

(Note: there is an implicit parameter of this)

If I have one iterator, the program will compile perfectly, but if I try to add in a second one (as shown above), the program will not compile at all.
Errors I get are:

```
Expected initializer before the * token
'current' is not declared in this scope
```

How do I validly declare the for loop such that thisCurrent and current will both be created?

Answer (score 2):

It should be written as:

```
for (ListNode* thisCurrent = head, *current = s.head; thisCurrent != NULL,   
    current != NULL; thisCurrent = thisCurrent->next) {
```

Do not write the type name `ListNode` twice. Also, please review your loop termination condition since the result of `thisCurrent != NULL` has no effect at all.